# Renaming buttons in dialog

Tags: dialog

I'm using bash and `dialog` to create curses menu.
For example

```
dialog --menu "Choose Next or Back" 15 50 4 Blah "blah"
```

this has OK and Cancel buttons.

Is there a way to rename 'OK' button to 'Next' and 'Cancel' button to 'Back'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following works

```
dialog --ok-label "Next" --cancel-label "Back" --menu "Choose Next or Back" 15 50 4 Blah "blah"
```